# Deducing Template Arguments for Member Functions and Variables

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, std-function

Apologies for the confusing title, I couldn't find a clearer way to express my question. I'm trying to use std::functions for implementing callbacks. The idea is to map "actions" to functions and provide an easy interface to keep track of which functions to call when a certain action happens.

Here's a simplified version of my class:

```
template<typename ID, typename Return, typename ...Args>
class A
{
public:
    void Register(ID id, std::function<Return(Args...)> funct)
    {
        m_listeners.emplace(id, funct);
    }
    A() {}
    ~A() {}
private:
    std::unordered_multimap<ID, std::function<Return(Args...)> > m_listeners;

};
```

What I really want is A to have only 1 template template
so when A is declared underlying container can still accept function with any return type and any number of arguments.

I don't have much experience with templates I'm not even sure what I'm trying to do is possible, but I need to hide the template parameters for unordered_multimap from class A.

What I'm trying to do would look something like this:

```
template<typename ID>
class A
{
public:
    template<typename Return, typename ...Args>
    void Register(ID id, std::function<Return(Args...)> funct)
    {
        m_listeners.emplace(id, funct);
    }
    A() {}
    ~A() {}
private:
    template<typename Return, typename ...Args>
    std::unordered_multimap<ID, std::function<Return(Args...)> > m_listeners;
};
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Use type-erasure techniques! Learn and explore it first.

Comment: @Nawaz Type-erasure is not something I'm familiar with, I'll definitely look into it, Thanks!

Comment: How do you plan on calling a function which takes an unknown number of parameters each with an unknown type? What do you plan on doing with the return values which are also of unknown type?

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do that. In your second example, the `Register` method and the container require knowing the return and argument types of your callbacks. Thus you must templatize A with that.

What you *could* do is simplify the class signature down to this:

```
#include <unordered_map>
template<typename ID, typename F>
class A
{
public:
    void Register(ID id, std::function<F> funct)
    {
        m_listeners.emplace(id, funct);
    }
    A() {}
    ~A() {}
private:
    std::unordered_multimap<ID, std::function<F> > m_listeners;
};
A<int, void(long)> a;
```

Comment: I still do not understand why my answer has been demoted without explanation.